# Tell Grails Only which JDK to use

Tags: java, grails, java-6

I'm on Windows.
Grails project needs JDK 1.6. As this is a truly compromised version, I don't want to set it as my user or system JAVA_HOME. I only want grails to use the ancient version. does setting it in the command line with "set" change the path permanently or only for the running instance?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this project won't work with a later version of Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set` to set the `JAVA_HOME` from the command line will only set that environment variable within the scope of the command/temrinal/console and not system wide. Assuming you are using `cmd.exe`.